# Should we have a separate delete recommendation for duplicate-suggestion link-only answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

One of the options to recommend deletion in the Low Quality Answers review queue (and now in the Late Answers queue as well) is for link-only answers. While this is fine for ***external*** links, it is a bit problematic for internal links - i.e. links to other questions/answers on the site.

I don't have concrete numbers but quite often while reviewing, I encounter answers that are link-only ***to other posts in the site*** (most recent example I encountered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530372/6045800) (deleted)). My problem is that the current link-only option is not so good for these cases:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
> essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
> Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

The main problem with this message is that the suggestion to include the essential parts of the answer here is mostly wrong in these cases as we want to avoid duplication and simply copying another answer shouldn't be encouraged.

I was thinking if we should add a new option for link-only answers, linking to content in the site. Something along the lines of the mods' message for duplicated answers:

> Please don't post links to other posts as answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [flag the question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). If the questions are not duplicates,
> you must tailor your answer specifically to the question.

---

I'm posting this question as a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) to see what the community thinks and might post as a feature request on MSE if there's an agreement.

Comment: I encounter this often as well. Note that flagging requires 15 rep, so maybe that message needs something for the 1 rep posters similar to the auto-comment about comments, that they can flag "*once they have enough reputation*"

Comment: @GinoMempin Good point! I updated a bit the message suggestion to match the other current options

Comment: They are essentially comments pointing to duplicates (and thus this ***important information*** ought to be kept by converting them to a comment to the question (short of an automatic close vote)).

Comment: "While this is fine for external links, it is a bit problematic for internal links" can you elaborate this argument? Why it's problematic for internal links?

Comment: @Braiam the following paragraph does that: *"The main problem with this message is that the suggestion to include the essential parts of the answer here is mostly wrong in these cases as we want to avoid duplication and simply copying another answer shouldn't be encouraged."*

Comment: Note that there's also a(n obscure) feature of [trivial answer converted to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/241919).

Comment: @Tomerikoo well, the link only answer already covers that point: you need to include the relevant parts of the referenced link, if you can't, then just don't post it as answer.

Comment: Should definitely have another delete reason, and I agree with your general premise here as well. I don't particularly like the suggested text though, that needs work.

Comment: @Travis what do you think is missing? Please, feel free to post an answer with a suggestion for the text

Comment: The "Once you have sufficient reputation" (+ some useless "What is Reputation" Link (https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)) could mention how much Rep is needed for "that"...! :grrr...!: :idea:

Comment: @chivracq the link for the flagging privilege details that, and anyway I was just following the format of other messages to be consistent. Again, feel free to post an answer with a different suggestion

Comment: "The main problem with this message is that the suggestion to include the essential parts of the answer" well, that's already included on the generic link only comment, so I don't know why you want another more specific.

Comment: @Braiam Tomerikoo already answered *why* and it's in the question -  "The main problem with this message is that the suggestion to include the essential parts of the answer here is mostly wrong in these cases as we want to avoid duplication and simply copying another answer shouldn't be encouraged.". If you don't think that reason is enough, that's one thing, but the reason is right there

Comment: @Braiam you seem to have stopped reading right before the key part - *"The main problem with this message is that the suggestion to include the essential parts of the answer here __is mostly wrong__"*

Comment: Is not wrong, it's correct, if followed to the T you would have answers referencing each other. In fact, it would create a autoflag so a moderator can come along and fix the issue. Also, considering that there's no a trivial amount of answers that answer more than 1 question, duplicate flagging is factually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### I like this idea, and I think we should make a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) for it

My only reservation is that this can be frustrating for low-rep (under 15 points) who have no other way to interact with the question *but* to post answers.

This [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1537216/link-only-answers-that-suggest-duplicate-questions-split-by-early-privileges?opt.withExecutionPlan=true) shows there's some of them, if I've written it correctly.

So while this is ok when the answerer has more than 15 reputation:

> Please don't post links to other posts as answers. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [flag the question as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). If the questions are not duplicates, you must tailor your answer specifically to the question.

If they have less reputation, it's not helpful to them to be told not to post an answer as they can't do anything else, and we still want them to find the duplicates.

Instead it would be good if the reviewer could confirm it is a valid duplicate suggestion, and whatever action taken puts the answer into a 'convert to duplicate suggestion' queue, similar to flagging as 'not an answer' puts into a queue 'to (potentially) be converted into a comment' (at last that's what happens on the stack I moderate). Then the system records two votes for that suggestion when confirmed.

What do people think? Worth discussing this idea more?

Comment: I agree with the fact that lower than 15 rep users will be frustrated, but this is no different from simple comment-answers. The deletion message is similar (*"once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment"*) and those "answers" are simply deleted - not all get converted to comments. At least the 15 rep for flagging is much lower than the 50 for comments. It just requires an upvote and two good edits... My suggestion is simply to make the message the most fitting for the scenario not to confuse new users and help them get better acquainted with the rules of the site

Comment: @Tomerikoo you make a good point!